# How do I transfer the user's score to another scene in Swift and SpriteKit?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I have three scenes, a MainMenu Scene, A GamePlay Scene, and a GameOver Scene. The user gets its score in the gameplay scene, and I'm wanting to transfer that score over to the GameOver scene. How can I do this? (If you need my code or more information, just ask!)

Comment: @JoshSchalbach It is always a good idea to show what you have tried so far :) Most of downvotes comes from the fact that question lacks of required information or when looks like that original poster asks for complete solution without even trying to solve something by himself :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [NSUserDefaults](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/) class as an easiest solution...

In your GameplayScene you set score into persistent storage.

```
let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
defaults.setInteger(score, forKey: "scoreKey")

defaults.synchronize()
```

Later in GameOver scene, you read persistent storage like this:

```
let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
let score = defaults.integerForKey("scoreKey")
println(score)
```

About synchronize() method (from the docs):

> Because this method is automatically invoked at periodic intervals,
>   use this method only if you cannot wait for the automatic
>   synchronization (for example, if your application is about to exit) or
>   if you want to update the user defaults to what is on disk even though
>   you have not made any changes.

Or I guess you can make a public property (score) on a GameOver scene, and when transitioning, to set that property (from a Gameplay scene) with a current score.

Similarly, you can set a value to [userData](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKNode_Ref/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/SKNode/userData) property which every node has, like this:

```
 newScene.userData?.setValue(score, forKey: "scoreKey")
```

**EDIT:**

NSUserDefaults would be a preferred way if you are interested into a persistence (making a value available between app launches). Otherwise, you can use userData or a struct like pointed by KnightOfDragon in his example.

Comment: Thanks so much. That was my last thing to do with my game! Now on to uploading to the appstore :)

Answer (score 2):

An alternative to NSUserDefaults would be to create a struct that would house all your global data

```
struct GlobalData
{
  static var gold = 0;
  static var coins = 0;
  static var lives = 0;
}
```

Then you would just use it like this:

```
let score = Global.score;
```

and

```
Global.score += 10;
```