# SpriteKit: Why does it wait one round for the score to update? (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, nsuserdefaults

In one scene, I have this code:

```
let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
defaults.setInteger(score, forKey: "scoreKey")

defaults.synchronize()
```

When the user makes contact with the gap, the code runs:

```
 score++
```

If the user hits an obstacle, the GameOverScene takes over. Here's the code I have for the GameOverScene to move the score to scene to scene:

```
let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
let score = defaults.integerForKey("scoreKey")
scoreLabel.text = "\(score)"
```

However, there's a bug in my code where the scoreLabel doesn't update its text. For example, let's say a user scores 1 and dies. When he dies, the gameOverScene will come up and say that the score was 1. Then, lets say the user clicks restart, and scores 5 and then dies. In the GameOverScene, the scoreLabel will say 1.

Please help me!

Comment: When do you call `defaults.synchronize()`?  If you don't call it right before swapping over to the GameOverScene, then the score will certainly not update.

Comment: @JoshSchlabach NSUserDefaults acts like a persistent storage. Means if you save a score to it, the score will persist between multiple app launches. And like Gliderman pointed, synchronize() should be called if you want to make sure that score is syncronized between in-memory cache with defaults database (otherwise it is called automatically but with a random time delay). If you are just trying to pass a score from one scene to the other without perserving it for the next app launch, the you don't need defaults and you can use global struct, custom property or userData SKNode's property ...

Comment: So in which scenario you are interested in ? :)

Comment: @Whirlwind I'm interested in the global struct, but I don't know how to use it.

Comment: @JoshSchlabach You can do it like pointed in your previous question : http://stackoverflow.com/a/33674911/3402095. In that post I assumed that you are interested in preserving the score between app launches to maintain the highscore, but it seems that you just want to pass single value to the next scene, so I pointed about single custom property ( on a GameOverScene) as well. If you had to store multiple values, then global struct would be more appropriate.

Comment: @Whirlwind where would I put the global struct? What scene?

Comment: Because I tried it last night and it didn't work.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to really call synchronise anymore if you use iOS 8 or above. This is recommended by Apple, yet a lot of people still do it. So get rid of that line if you still use it.

My preferred way for game data is using a singleton GameData class with NSCoding. No need to add variables all over the place and much cleaner. I advise you reading this.

http://www.raywenderlich.com/63235/how-to-save-your-game-data-tutorial-part-1-of-2

You can also integrate iCloud key value storage that way, it is very easy as its similar to user defaults (see my example below)

Anyway to start you off here is a simple example of how this could look.

```
import Foundation


/// Keys
private struct Key {
    static let encodedData = "encodedData"
    static let highScore = "highScore"
}

class GameData: NSObject, NSCoding {

// MARK: - Static Properties

/// Shared instance
static let shared: GameData = {
     if let decodedData = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: Key.encodedData) as? GameData {
        return gameData
    } else {
        print("No data, creating new")
        return GameData()
    }
}    

// MARK: - Properties

/// Defaults
private let localDefaults = UserDefaults.standard
private let iCloudDefaults = NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore.default()

/// Progress (not saved, no need for saving the score because of the highScore var. Still have here for global single access)
var score = 0

/// Progress (saved)
var highScore = 0

// MARK: - Init
private override init() {
    super.init()
    print("GameData init")
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(updateFromCloud), name: NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore.didChangeExternallyNotification, object: iCloudDefaults)
    iCloudDefaults.synchronize()
}

// MARK: - Convenience Init
convenience required init?(coder decoder: NSCoder) {
    self.init()
    print("GameData convenience init")

    // Progress
    highScore = decoder.decodeInteger(forKey: Key.highScore)
}

// MARK: - Encode
func encodeWithCoder(encoder: NSCoder) {

    // Progress
    encoder.encodeInteger(highScore, forKey: Key.highScore)

// MARK: - User Methods

/// Save
func save() {

    if score > highScore {
        highScore = score
    }

    saveLocally()
    saveToCloud()
}

// MARK: - Internal Methods

/// Save locally
private func saveLocally() {
    let encodedData = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(self)
    localDefaults.setObject(encodedData, forKey: Key.encodedData)
}

/// Save to icloud
private func saveToCloud() {
    print("Saving to iCloud")

    // Highscores
    if (highScore > iCloudDefaults.objectForKey(Key.highScore) as? Int ?? Int()) {
        iCloudDefaults.setObject(highScore, forKey: Key.highScore)
    }


/// Update from icloud
func updateFromCloud() {
    print("Updating from iCloud")

    // Highscores
    highScore = max(highScore, iCloudDefaults.object(forKey: Key.highScore) as? Int ?? Int())

    // Save
    saveLocally()
}
```

Now in any scene if you want to use the score or saved highScore property you for example could say

```
GameData.shared.score++
```

or

```
scoreLabel.text = "\(GameData.shared.score)"
highScoreLabel.text = "\(GameData.shared.highScore)"
```

All your text labels will be updated immediately if you transition to a new scene or update the .text property. No need for userDefault sync etc.

Calling ...shared... will also initialise the helper. If you want to load gameData as soon as your game has launched you could call

```
GameData.shared
```

in your appDelegate or viewController. Its probably not really needed but your could still do it just to ensure the helper is initialised as soon as the game is launched.

If you want to save you call

```
GameData.shared.save()
```

Just remember to reset the score back to 0 in your gameScene.swift in the ViewDidLoad method.

```
GameData.shared.score = 0
```

This should make your life much easier. If you want to use iCloud all you have to do is go to your target and capabilities and turn on iCloud and tick keyValueStorage (not core data). Done.

Note: 
To take it even a step further you could get the KeychainWrapper helper from JRendel on gitHub. Than instead of using NSUserDefaults to store the encoded gameData you use keychain, its dead simple to use.

Answer (score 1):

You can save your score like below code:

```
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setInteger(score, forKey: "scoreKey")
```

Then you can get your score was saved like below code:

```
  if NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("scoreKey") != nil
    {
      score = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("scoreKey") as! Int
    }
      scoreLabel.text = "\(score)"
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question from your comment about using global structure...

According to docs :

> Global variables are variables that are defined outside of any
>   function, method, closure, or type context.

Means you should define your struct right after the import statements at the top of the any file.

You make a structure like pointed from the link I've posted in comments, like this (I've placed the struct definition inside the GameScene.swift file):

```
struct GlobalData
 {
    static var gold  = 0;
    static var coins = 0;
    static var lives = 0;
    static var score = 0;
 }
```

This struct will be available in GameOverScene as well. So, before transition, you will do something like :

```
GlobalData.score = 20
GlobalData.coins = 10
//etc.
```

And in your GameOverScene you will access it like this:

```
scoreNode.text = String(GlobalData.score)//scoreNode is SKLabelNode
```

Comment: Alright sorry for late notice- Okay first, I didn't add the globaldata struct yet because I think I found out the problem. Let's say the user scores 5 and then dies. In the game over scene, the score displays "5." In the next round, let's say the user scores 0 and dies. In the gameoverscene, the score will display 5. So basically, the problem is when the user scores 0. The score doesn't update. Also, when the user scores 0 two times in a row, the score will update to 0. Please help me fix this, because I am unsure how to fix it.

Comment: It also is doing this for the global struct.

Comment: @JoshSchalbach It looks like a code logic problem to me, but I can't say anything without seeing the relevant code. It's up to you how you maintain the score. So, before every game start you should set the score to 0.