# Using NSCoding to get High Score and LifeTime Score in Swift / SpriteKit

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, swift2, persistent, nscoding

**Here is the dilemma.**

I have a class that manages high scores for a Sprite Kit Game.  The "high score" functionality works, however the "calculating all scores".

In the game, the player has to collect *berries*.  I want to keep track of a lifetime amount of *berries*.

Here is my class to manage high scores.

```
class Score: NSObject, NSCoding {

var score: Int
var highScore: Int
var lifeTimeScore: Int

static let DocumentsDirectory = NSFileManager().URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask).first!
static let ArchiveURL = DocumentsDirectory.URLByAppendingPathComponent("scores")

struct PropertyKey {
    static let highScoreKey = "high"
    static let currentScoreKey = "current"
    static let lifeTimeScoreKey = "life"
}

func encodeWithCoder(aCoder: NSCoder){
    aCoder.encodeObject(score, forKey: PropertyKey.currentScoreKey)
    aCoder.encodeObject(highScore, forKey: PropertyKey.highScoreKey)
    aCoder.encodeObject(lifeTimeScore, forKey: PropertyKey.lifeTimeScoreKey)

}

required convenience init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    let score = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey(PropertyKey.currentScoreKey) as! Int
    let highScore = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey(PropertyKey.highScoreKey) as! Int
    let lifeTimeScore = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey(PropertyKey.lifeTimeScoreKey) as! Int

    self.init(score: score, highScore: highScore, lifeTimeScore: lifeTimeScore)

}

init?(score: Int, highScore: Int, lifeTimeScore: Int!) {
    // Initialize stored properties.
    self.score = score
    self.highScore = highScore
    self.lifeTimeScore = lifeTimeScore

    super.init()
   }    
}
```

The problem comes when I go to load up the scores. Everything works if I remove the existence lifeTimeScore.  Yet as soon as I try to implement the little sucker, he throws me a

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

When I check the debugger, the problem is coming from the

```
let lifeTimeScore = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey(PropertyKey.lifeTimeScoreKey) as! Int
```

It really is confusing and I really am at a standstill.  Here is the GameModel Class that calls the Score class.  When I got to instantiate it with newGame().  I get the error.

```
class GameModel: NSObject {

private var highScore = Int()
private var berriesCaught: Int = NO_BERRIES_CAUGHT
private var lifeTimeBerries = Int()

var gameOver: Bool!
var damaged: Bool!

func newGame(){
    berriesCaught = NO_BERRIES_CAUGHT

    if (loadScores() != nil) {
        if let score = loadScores(){
            highScore = score.highScore
            lifeTimeBerries = score.lifeTimeScore
        }
    }

    checkGameState()
    damaged = false
}

func saveScores(){
    checkHighScore()
    lifeTimeBerries += berriesCaught
    if let scoreToken = Score(score: berriesCaught, highScore: highScore, lifeTimeScore: lifeTimeBerries){
        let isSuccessfulSave = NSKeyedArchiver.archiveRootObject(scoreToken, toFile: Score.ArchiveURL.path!)
        if !isSuccessfulSave {
            print("Failed to save scores")
        }
    }
}

func loadScores() -> Score? {
    return NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithFile(Score.ArchiveURL.path!) as? Score
}

func checkHighScore(){
    if let score = loadScores() {
        if berriesCaught > score.highScore {
            highScore = berriesCaught
        } else {
            highScore = score.highScore
        }
    } else{
        highScore = berriesCaught
    }
}
```

How can I fix it so that the lifeTimeBerries is getting properly added after each game?
How can I fix it so that it will load the correct values for the properties when I call loadScores()?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason you get a crash is because decoding objects for keys does not provide a default value if no key is found (e.g decodeBoolForKey defaults to false)

Therefore you need to adjust your code. As the other member also said, change the code to

```
let lifeTimeScore = aDecoder.decodeIntegerForKey(PropertyKey.lifeTimeScoreKey)
```

which will automatically set a default value if no key is found because it knows you are trying to decode an integer.

If you want use decodeObjectForKey you need to do some nil check first because there is no default value because you are decoding "AnyObject". The line

```
... as! Int
```

will force unwrap the objectForKey as an Int, but it might not be there and is therefore nil and than you get the crash. Either change it too

```
if aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey(PropertyKey.lifeTimeScoreKey) != nil {
     let lifeTimeScore = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey(PropertyKey.lifeTimeScoreKey) as! Int
}
```

or use this handy feature to put it in 1 line

```
 let lifeTimeScore = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey(PropertyKey.lifeTimeScoreKey) as? Int ?? Int()
```

Here it will check if a key exists (as? Int) and if it doesnt it will create a new default one (?? Int()).

Most likely the best way is to use IntegerForKey because your "lifeTimeScore" is an Int, only use ObjectForKey when you have too.

Comment: How would I ask a question that permits (if you're interested) you to step through the process of saving and retrieving some game data?

Comment: What do you mean permits? I like to do it with a Singleton class using NSCoding just like this question. Have a look here first and google about NSCoding.  Also check out the 2 links below. If you are still stuck ask a question with what you want to achieve and what code you have so far http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36725052/how-to-store-user-data-in-game-swift-spritekit/36746969#36746969     http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33684540/spritekit-why-does-it-wait-one-round-for-the-score-to-update-swift/33895778#33895778

Comment: I've been reading what I can about NSCoding for 2 full days, and going through it with someone on emails. And I'm gonig backwards.

Comment: Still try to read what I posted and if you are still stuck just ask a question with the code you have and what you want to do. I will help no problem.

Comment: I've said it already, I've read everything I can, on SO and blogs and the Apple docs. That includes your posts. That's explicitly why I'm asking you. You seem to be closest to having a holistic view of what's required, the steps and procedures, and what they're actually doing.

Comment: Ignoring NSUserDefaults, and focusing in on saving a dictionary made up of a conformed CGPoint (ie hashable) as Key, and SKSpriteNodes as the values... what are the steps involved in storing this dictionary, and retrieving it and then be able to query it for content? This is the entirety of my mission. And I'm at the end of my rope on what's the order... is it encode, then archive, then store then retrieve then unarchive then decode then reference?

Comment: Not this: Objective-C, and monkeySeeMonkeyDo, not a list of what's happening in site. https://www.raywenderlich.com/63235/how-to-save-your-game-data-tutorial-part-1-of-2, not this: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/read/12/3/fixing-project-10-nscoding as it's about using and abusing NSUserDefaults. Just a simple list of what's required, much like SteveIves has done for the prerequisites of ensuring physics work in SpriteKit. If it's not possible to do this because NSCoding is too varied in approaches and purposes, just say so. No need to get all whingy about what you consider rants.

Comment: The Hacking with swift one perfectly fine, NSCoding is not to save data, its to archive a class and than save that archive in something like user defaults or Keychain. Than later on you can decode the class from the saved archive in NSUserDefaults/Keychain.

Comment: What/how is the class saved? And loaded?

Comment: The class, as you can see in the question, has a decoding and encoding method (the 2 methods underneath struct PropertyKey). Those 2 methods encode and decode all the properties in that class that you selected. You basically end up with an archive and that archive is than saved in NSUserDefaults/Keychain. On app launch, when the class loads it will fetch the saved archive from UserDefaults/Keychain and decode it and update the properties in the class.

Comment: what calls are made, by whom, when, where, and how, to save and retrieve? I see the encode and decode, but that's like compress and decompress. Something activates them to make them act on the data in the class/object/instance/variable... but what is it that's actually called, by whom, to save and retrieve?

Comment: in the question above the methods called saveScores() and LoadScores(). You never call decode or encode yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Use this updated code and decoder method.

```
    func encodeWithCoder(aCoder: NSCoder){

    aCoder.encodeInt(score, forKey: PropertyKey.currentScoreKey)
    aCoder.encodeInt(highScore, forKey: PropertyKey.highScoreKey)
    aCoder.encodeInt(lifeTimeScore, forKey: PropertyKey.lifeTimeScoreKey)

}


required convenience init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {

    let score = aDecoder.decodeIntForKey(PropertyKey.currentScoreKey)
    let highScore = aDecoder.decodeIntForKey(PropertyKey.highScoreKey
    let lifeTimeScore = aDecoder.decodeIntForKey(PropertyKey.lifeTimeScoreKey)

    self.init(score: score, highScore: highScore, lifeTimeScore: lifeTimeScore)

}
```