# How to store user data in game? (swift, spritekit)

Tags: ios, class, sprite-kit

Let's say I had a game where in the beginning the user gets to choose a couple of things like name, gender, etc, and that will affect a lot of aspects in the game such as the sprite used to render the user, and the text that is displayed.

So every time I leave one area of the game and enter a new one I should figure out according to the user data - what sprite to use and what text to prep. Should I make a separate class with a dictionary just for the user's data and then just call it whenever I enter a new area? 
Thanks yall.

Comment: Whether it's a dictionary or real properties of a class is somewhat a matter of taste, but separating data from the objects that handle display rules is a good idea.  If you're not familiar with MVC, this might be a good time to read about it.  :)

Comment: @PhillipMills will do that!!

Comment: do you want to save this information for the next time the user opens the app?  or do you just want to save it for that play period?

Comment: @hamobi yes permanently saved

Comment: Do you need small pieces of arbitrary info saved or a large amount of data? iOS has a few ways of doing it which can be easier or harder to implement based on your needs

Comment: @hamobi it should just be a couple of string values or integers that i need to keep track of

Comment: i would just use NSUserDefaults.  check this out
https://www.hackingwithswift.com/read/12/2/reading-and-writing-basics-nsuserdefaults

Answer (score 4):

There is a few ways to do this.

I prefer to use a singleton GameData class with NSCoding to house all the properties (arrays, dictionaries etc) that need to be saved permanently.

I like it this way because it makes code more readable and also has the advantage that you can access the properties from anywhere in your project. This way it's also easy to include icloud key value storage.

You can read these 2 questions I answered for a simple example of how this can look

[SpriteKit: Why does it wait one round for the score to update? (Swift)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33684540/spritekit-why-does-it-wait-one-round-for-the-score-to-update-swift/33895778#33895778)

[Is there a better way to save a custom class to NSUserDefaults than encoding and decoding everything with NSCoder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35821732/is-there-a-better-way-to-save-a-custom-class-to-nsuserdefaults-than-encoding-and/35822781#35822781)

There is a also few good tutorials around such as this

https://www.hackingwithswift.com/read/12/3/fixing-project-10-nscoding

To securely save data you can/should use keychain. To read more about it check out this question.

[How secure is NSUserDefaults on iOS 8,9?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35900523/how-secure-is-nsuserdefaults-on-ios-8-9/35900835#35900835)