# How to save game progress in a SpriteKit game

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I'm currently working on a game using SpriteKit, GameplayKit, and JSTileMap. I'm trying to implement a function to save the game progress. I tried to use NSCoder to encode/decode all variables in each class, but XCode tells me that all classes using Entity and Component do not conform to NSCoding. So how do save my game data? Can I just encode everything from the main game scene and it would work?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Is Entity and Component classes that you made?

Comment: no, they are subclasses of GKEntity and GKComponent

Comment: ok so yes, you made them.  Just attach the NSCoding protocol to these classes and properly handle the decoding and encoding required by the protocol

Comment: that's exactly what the problem is. none of these classes allows me to attach the NSCoding protocol. I get an error message saying that they are not conformed to NSCoding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you are conforming to the NSCoding protocol correctly,  should look like this

```
class Entity : GKEntity,NSCoding
{
    func encodeWithCoder(aCoder: NSCoder)
    {

    }
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)
    {

    }
}

class Component : GKComponent,NSCoding
{
    func encodeWithCoder(aCoder: NSCoder)
    {

    }
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: I guess I should have asked if it was swift or objective-c,  it looks a little different for objective-c

Comment: it's written in swift. thanks for the example. that's what I did but got an error message on the very first line: class Entity: GKEntity, NSCoding { }. it won't allow me to put NSCoding there.

Comment: what error?  I have this in playground and I am not getting an error

Comment: sorry, i don't have access to my Xcode project at the moment. let me double check when i get home and let you know. thanks for the quick response.

Comment: I would double check that you are using NSCoding, not NSCoder

Comment: i got it to work. thanks so much. the reason i used to get the error msg was because i didn't implement the required init. thanks again.

Comment: the required init is the decoding process, can't encode without a way to decode lol

Answer (score 1):

How about creating a Singleton class called GameData that houses all the properties you need to be saved like score, highscores etc.

Something like the example I posted here
[SpriteKit: Why does it wait one round for the score to update? (Swift)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33684540/spritekit-why-does-it-wait-one-round-for-the-score-to-update-swift/33895778#33895778)

As others have said your question is quite broad.

Comment: Thanks for the link, but I'm trying to save the actual progress of the game, including all entities's current position on map along with their HP/Mana/EXP, etc. Would a singleton class be able to handle all that?

Comment: Himhh probably, might be better to just use NSCODING for each level. It depends how your game is structured

Answer (score 0):

For what its worth, StackOverflows excels at helping developers solve very specific problems in very specific code.  A question like this is more asking for subjective advice and will be frowned on by the thousands of self-appointed SO question-czars.  That said, here is my take:

I am struggling with a very similar problem right now in an app I am creating that relies on a number of objects and deeply nested dictionaries.  I started trying to NSEncode the objects themselves and unpacking and loading those objects during launch.  I soon found this to be problematic, error prone, and overly complicated. The approach I am attempting now is slightly different.  What I am doing is during the game occasionally saving those key dictionaries by converting them to NSData sets and storing them in a NSUserDefault.  When the game launches, I unpack all of those dictionaries and build objects with them.  I find this method (so far) easier, and just saving the data that the objects are built with saves space as well.

Comment: thanks for sharing your ideas. i'm gonna look into it as well.