# NSCoder Conversion types Xcode 7.2.1 Cannot convert value of type 'String' to expected argument type 'NSCoder'

Tags: xcode, swift, sprite-kit, nscoding, persistent-storage

[Error Codes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OKX3O.png)

I have been researching the multitude of ways to save persistent data across scenes, NSUserdefaults, Global Structs, Dict, etc. and like many others it depends on the game, you have, and how the game (IMO) will evolve overtime. For my situation, I do not have a persistent game scene, where game logic causes an increase in difficulty. I have 13 game scenes, 7 of which need votes for that scene,   2 of which need to display a highVotes.

1.) Having that votes, populate from each game scene to the highVotes, 
2.)Storing that votes,

//example in gameScene

```
var vote: Int = 0 { 
    didSet {
        gameScore.text = "Votes: \(vote)" 
    }
```

Error: when trying to pull the score data from the GameScene obj-C Error

Created a Global Scene: (suggested many times on here, everything is there, scene data, sounds, etc. Cannot seem to get the scene data to load when implementing NSObject, NSCoding. 
       BaseScene
 Did not like the NSObject and NSCoding in the Class declaration either I figured that out though.

```
 struct GlobalData {
        //other Global Data
        static let encodedData = "encodedData"
        static let highVotes = "highVotes"


convenience required init?(coder decoder: NSCoder) {
                self.init()
                print("BaseScene convenience init")

                //      // Progress

                        highVotes = decoder.decodeIntegerForKey(GlobalData.highVotes)


                }


                // Mark: - Encode

                override func encodeWithCoder(encoder: (NSCoder)) {

                //Progress

                encoder.encodeInteger(highVotes, forKey: GlobalData.highVotes)
```

Error Code is in the picture. My scenes were converted to strings now they wont cooperate. It claims it wants GameScene(coder: GameScene) nope!!

```
/// Progress (not saved, no need for saving the score because of the highScore var. Still have here for global single access

    var votes: Int = 0

/// Progress (saved)

    var highVotes: Int = 0



           case SceneType.GameScene:
           sceneToLoad = GameScene(coder:GameScene) //nope 
//Error cannot create a single element tuple with an element label.
```

was following this example: [Option other than USERDefaults](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33684540/spritekit-why-does-it-wait-one-round-for-the-score-to-update-swift/33895778#33895778)

I figure I would reference that instead of posting the whole code.

my goal was to implement the ability in one globalfile instead of breaking out the variables. Any suggestions would be helpful?? If you need more code, please ask. I modified the code to fit my project, yet its not co-operating. See pic Thanks again. (Please be gentle LOL) For real I just need to get this done, everyone has a different way, and I have taken a stab at all of them.

```
import Foundation

class VoteData: NSObject, NSCoding {

static let sharedInstance = VoteData.loadInstance()

   struct Key {

        static let encodedData = "encodedData"
        static let highVotes = "highVotes"

}

/// Defaults 

    private let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    private let iCloudDefaults = NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore.defaultStore()

/// Progress (not saved, no need for saving the score because of the highScore 

    var votes: Int = 0

/// Progress (saved) 

    var highVotes: Int = 0

// Mark: Init 

    private override init() {
        super.init()
        print("VoteData init")
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "updateFromCloud", name: NSUbiquitousKeyValueStoreDidChangeExternallyNotification, object: iCloudDefaults)
        iCloudDefaults.synchronize()

}

// MARK: - Convenience Init 
    convenience required init?(coder decoder: NSCoder) {
        self.init()
        print("GameData convenience init")

      // Progress 

        highVotes = decoder.decodeIntegerForKey(Key.highVotes)


}


// Mark: - Encode 

func encodeWithCoder(encoder: NSCoder) {

//Progress

encoder.encodeInteger(highVotes, forKey: Key.highVotes)
```

Save

```
    func save() {

        if votes > highVotes {

            highVotes = votes

        }



    saveLocally()
    saveToCloud()


  }
    }


/// Load instance

private class func loadInstance() -> VoteData {
    if let decodedData: AnyObject = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey(Key.encodedData) {
        print("Decoding Data")

        let voteData = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithData(decodedData as! NSData) as! VoteData
        return voteData
    } else {

        print("No data, creating new")
        return VoteData()
      }
    }





/// Save Locally 

    private func saveLocally() {
        let encodedData = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(self)
        defaults.setObject(encodedData, forKey: Key.encodedData)

       }

/// Save to ICLOUD 

    private func saveToCloud() {
        print("Saving to iCloud")

                 // Highvotes
    if (highVotes > iCloudDefaults.objectForKey(Key.highVotes) as?  Int ??  Int()) {

        iCloudDefaults.setObject(highVotes, forKey: Key.highVotes)

       }
     }




/// Update from ICLOUD 

    func updateFromCloud() {
        print("Updating from iCloud")

     // HighVotes 

        highVotes = max(highVotes, iCloudDefaults.objectForKey(Key.highVotes) as? Int ?? Int())

        // Save
        saveLocally()
    }
   }
```

EDIT*************

yes it is easier to make global variables and I look forward to doing so, and collecting that data: What I failed to realize before I went into the rabbit hole was this important line of code, that keeps showing its face:

```
required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}



let ScoreDefault = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    let Score = ScoreDefault.valueForKey("Score") as! NSInteger
    NSLog("\(Score)")

    let HighscoreDefault = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    Highscore = HighscoreDefault.valueForKey("Highscore") as! NSInteger



 NSLog("\(Highscore)")
```

calling that score again using NSCoder !!! As my Game grows and gets bigger, I can get super fancy and implement some of these thoughtful solutions, Im tracking two variables, in my game at the moment so no need to make it complicated.

Base Scene for values converted into Strings: My scenes that are called by file name:

```
convenience init(string aString:NSString) {
        fatalError("init(string:) has not been implemented")
```

Comment: It should be a class, not a struct

Comment: The struct is defined before the class, so combining both approaches is no good?

Comment: That was a quick response

Comment: Okay so I am a member of the RW website and amongst others, I have worked through many of his tutorials, and he has plenty of examples of public functions, typically for audio, SKEffects, Mathematical adjustments for node movement, and physics, This interpretation whether it is user error on my part or whatever, the methods are not able to be called. I am assuming because they are marked private, because my helper classes, have public access to throughout my project. This one does not. Am I missing something from the code I provided. Its exact, and the reason I did make it that way. Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33192675/using-nsuserdefaults-on-arrays/33194374#33194374

Comment: @ leo I checked out your other post seems to be a quality you are very good at, and yep, as a lot people have stated its referenced a lot. So my understanding is that I have to use theNSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithData to access the stored the data and present this information throughout my project as needed. My question is do I do away with the original swift I created, which seems obvious yet I thought I would ask to be sure, and being I am not dealing with arrays, I will just create classes to convert my objects into strings. Applies to Int as well. Thank you LE