# Passing Score in between Scenes in Sprite Kit With Swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, sprite-kit, 2d-games

I have a GameScene file, a GameOverScene file and a Main Menu Scene file. I have a score variable that I would like to pass between GameScene and Game OverScene. Then a HiScore Variable that I would like to save and pass between GameOver and Main Menu. What is the best way to do this? Thank You. I have looked at other examples such as using a struct but when I tried to implement it, it didn't work when accessing from a different file.

Comment: Try NSUserDefaults *or*--even better (for some things)--create a global variable (outside of all classes) and simply set the value of that global variable after the game, and then access it from any other scene. Makes sense? For stuff like high score, you might want user defaults, but for stuff like the last score, you'll probably want to use a global variable. Easy and effective :-)

Comment: @KobiGreene Like Dopapp pointed, if you are interested in persistence (for a highscore), then you should use NSUserDefaults. Otherwise you can use some kind of a global variable. Check out both answers in [StackOverflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33641684/3402095) for a code examples.